# Is it possible to deploy custom workflow activities to Office 365

Tags: workflow, office-365, sandbox-solution

Is it possible to deploy SharePoint 2013 style **custom workflow activities** and deploy it to Office 365 environment as sandboxed solution?

Or maybe, it is possible to deploy it as an app and use it in host web?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check out similar question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/98688/12947